# jQuery element looping like a playlist under div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to program a effect like digital signage in the webpage but I am not sure how to do it, please kindly offer some help in here.

I have several div in the page which is the place holder of region.
For each region, there are multiple media inside.

For a defined duration the current media will play other will be hidden (or destroy) and the subsequence media will come out in the same position.

Most importantly, when the last element is reach, i will replay the whole sequence again. so the webpage keep rolling.

I have made a JSFiddle for this case, please kindly help on this and i have spend a day on that on my poor coding.....

https://jsfiddle.net/vx8Lp9xd/11/

**HTML**

```
 <body>
        <div class='timecontrol region1 position' >
            <video duration='30' width="320" height="240" controls class='position'>
              <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <video duration='0' width="320" height="240" controls class='position'>
              <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>    
        </div>
        <div class='timecontrol region2 position'>
            <img class='position' duration='10' src='1.gif'></img>
            <img class='position' duration='20' src='2.gif'></img>
        </div>  
        <div class='readyState'></div>
        </body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkContainer () {
  if($('#readyState').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
    $('.timecontrol').each(function() {
        var elements = new Array();
        elements = $(this).children().toArray();
        for (element in elements){

            $(element).not(element).remove();
            $(element).show();


$(element).delay(parseInt($(element).attr('duration'))*1000).hide(0);
            }
        });   
      } 
    }   
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            checkContainer();
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.position{
    position:absolute;
}

.region1{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:320px;
    width:240px;
}

.region2{
    position:absolute;
    top:px;
    left:320px;
    height:320px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px;
}
```

Comment: There are likely many plugins available that have exactly this functionality, I'd google around for that a bit before re-inventing the [media slider](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=media%20slider)

Comment: Thanks DelightedD0D, i am doing OK now with image and text but cant stop the playing of video and play it only when it is visible...

Answer (score 0):

A [recursive function](http://techterms.com/definition/recursivefunction) (a function that calls itself) is probably better suited to your needs here than `.each()` or a `for` loop. Here is how I would do it with recursion:

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7z5uof1/2/)

```js
function checkContainer() {
    if ($('#readyState').is(':visible')) { //if the container is visible on the page
        $('.timecontrol').each(function () {
            change($(this).children());
        });
    }
}
function change(elements, index) {
    index = !index || index > elements.length - 1 ? 0 : index; // if index is higher than the index of the last element or not set at all, default to 0

    var element = $(elements[index]);
    var timeframe = parseInt(element.attr('duration')) * 1000;
    element.siblings().hide();
    element.show();
    if (element[0].tagName.match(/video/i)) element[0].play();
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.hide(0);
        if (element[0].tagName.match(/video/i)) element[0].pause();
        change(elements, index+1); // recursively call this same functoin passing in the elements and the index of the next one up
    }, timeframe);

}
$(document).ready(function () {
   checkContainer();
});
```

```css
.position {
    position:absolute;
}
.region1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:320px;
    width:240px;
}
.region2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:px;
    left:320px;
    height:320px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='timecontrol region1 position'>
    <video duration='6' width="320" height="240" controls class='position'>
        <source src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/functional.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video duration='6' width="320" height="240" controls class='position'>
        <source src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div class='timecontrol region2 position'>
    <img class='position' duration='10' src='https://placeimg.com/350/150/any'></img>
    <img class='position' duration='20' src='https://placeimg.com/350/150/animals'></img>
</div>
<div id='readyState'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks delightedD0D and fantastic!, i am afraid that the code is not quite working on 2nd movie playback, it wont change back to first clip at 6 sec. and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Shoudl i use eventlistener for video tag in this case? It seems the time will shift after some playback if i use setInterval ...please correct me if i am wrong.